# Scope values to a requested content

Tags: angularjs

I have a view that contains a button, when the button is clicked, a `$http.get` request is executed and the content is appended on the view.

View:

```
<button ng-click="includeContent()">Include</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.includeContent = function() {
    $http.get('url').success(function(data) {
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = data;
    }
}
```

The content to include:

```
<h1>Hey, I would like to be {{ object }}</h1>
```

How can I scope a value to object? Do I need to approach this in a complete different way?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in directive [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) is the way you are looking for.

Beware, that `ng-bind-html` requires a sanitized string, which is either done automatically when the correct libary is found or it can be done manually (`$sce.trustAsHtml`).
Don't forget to inject `$sce` in your controller.

```
$scope.includeContent = function() {
    $http.get('url').success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
    }
}

<button ng-click="includeContent()">Include</button>
<div ng-bind-html="data"></div>
```

As you also want to interpolate your requested HTML, I suggest using [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) or, if it can contain whole directives or should have a full fledged two-way-data-binding, use [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) instead.

In your case alter the assignment to

```
$scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml($interpolate(data)($scope));
```

Don't forget to inject $interpolate/$compile aswell.

As I don't know about your $scope structure I assume that "object" is available in this scope. If this isn't the case then change the $scope parameter to whatever object contains  your interpolation data.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `Error: [$sce:unsafe]` in the console

Comment: You should write: $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);

Comment: Now it works, but how can I assign a value to `{{ object }}` that's a part of the requested HTML?

Comment: It works perfectly and you showed me I was approaching this in a non-angular way. Thanks  for helping!

Comment: Always a pleasure to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a controller to do this (I imagine you are since you're using `$scope`).

```
ctrl function () {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.includeContent = function () {
        $http.get("url").success(function (data) {
            ctrl.object = data;
        });
    };
}

<div ng-controller="ctrl as ctrl">
    <button ng-click="ctrl.includeContent()">Include</button>
    <div id="container">
       <h1 ng-show="ctrl.object">Hey, I would like to be {{ctrl.object}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not select an element and append the data to it. Angular does it for you. That's what is magic about angular.

In your controller's scope, just update `object` and angular does the heavy-lifting

```
$scope.includeContent = function() {
    $http.get('url').success(function(data) {
        $scope.object = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's html code from a server, then you should use the 'ng-bind-html' attribute:

```
<button ng-click="includeContent()">Include</button>
<div id="container" ng-bind-html="htmlModel.ajaxData"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.htmlModel = {ajaxData:''};
$scope.includeContent = function() {
$http.get('url').success(function(data) {
        $scope.htmlModel.ajaxDataL = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `ng-bind-html` as suggested.

Another way is with `$compile`:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $compile) {
    $scope.error='error!!!';
    $scope.includeContent = function() {
      $http.get('url').success(function(data) {
          var elm = angular.element(document.getElementById('container')).html(data);
          $compile(elm)($scope);
      }).error(function(){
          var elm = angular.element(document.getElementById('container')).html('{{error}}');
          $compile(elm)($scope);
      })
    }
});
```

Also, typically in angular, when you want to manipulate the DOM you use directives.

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/trHYqdPYtmV35pOlFKpc)

Comment: Typically in angular, you don't want to manipulate the DOM directly. Sry, couldn't resist.

Comment: @Pr0gr4mm3r I agree in this case it's not really needed, but there's nothing inherently wrong with doing complex manipulations, which aren't easily done with native directives, in your own directives. That's a part of the point of making directives.

Comment: Of course nothing is wrong with complex DOM manipulation, Angular isn't almighty afterall. I just meant that "document.getElementById('container')" isn't the angular way of doing things. But this is too offtopic to discuss it further.

Comment: @Pr0gr4mm3r Agreed. It's why I mentioned directives, in which you would have access to the element.